# YA bestsellers by reader's gender

Tags: gender, readers, sales

There are lists with YA bestsellers. What they don't tell me is which books are bought by girls, and which by boys.

Are there any resources showing (YA) bestsellers by reader's gender?

Comment: You could only do that with a poll, generally.  Most YA books are bought by the parents.  However, Scholastic (and some other publishers?) sell many of their books at school book fairs, so they might actually have the data you seek.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [interview](http://childrensbooks.about.com/od/5youngadultbooks/a/Teen-Reading-Trends-Current.htm) with the president of the Young Adult Library Services (YALSA), a division of the American Library Association (ALA). She mentions that there are very few male readers of YA *fiction*, but that boys tend to read nonfiction on subjects that interest them.

I've attended YA writing panels at SF conventions, and almost all of the published YA authors attending are female. Their work tends to have strong romance elements, which I'd guess would appeal more to a female audience. A couple of them also mentioned that their sons don't want to be seen reading books with 'girly' covers. These authors would be considered more 'midlist' than bestsellers.